# A word for the sweet spot between underwhelming and overwhelming

Tags: single-word-requests

In UI design (for apps etc), it’s important to get the level of complexity right. If there are too many features and settings, the user gets overwhelmed and confused. If not enough, they feel underwhelmed and limited. Either way, they struggle to do whatever it is they wanted to do.

Too simple: “It’s too basic, I wish there was an option to change the font!”

Too complex: “It’s too confusing, whenever I change the font it automatically changes this other thing, which I neither understand nor want!”

Just right: *Silence - the user just changes the font and thinks nothing of it*

I’m struggling to find any language to refer to that sweet spot between “too simple/unpowerful” and “too complex/overwhelming/confusing”.

Any suggestions?

Sample sentence: “This app is so _____, I love it!”

(I considered “whelming” but it turns out that just has the same meaning as “overwhelming”.)

Comment: While technically synonymous with "overwhelming", (and "underwhelming" is an unpaired word in modern English), I have heard "whelming" as a nonce word to humorously describe expectations being perfectly met. I know Robin from Young Justice often jokingly references being "whelmed."

Comment: *bang in the middle of the Goldilocks zone* Sadly, that's 8 words, but I just don't care, all these searches for single words where a slack handful can be so much more expressive ...

Comment: User-friendly? A happy medium? Optimized? Just right? Sweet?

Comment: I feel it's necessary to clarify- overwhelming and underwhelming are technically opposite, but in terms of connotation, there's a bit of a difference. Overwhelming means that something has too many functions, while underwhelming refers more to something that's 'disappointing, or not up to expectation' than to a lack of functions. I wouldn't say that an app is underwhelming, I'd say that it's 'too basic.'

Comment: **right on the mark**, is what I'd use.

Comment: Obviously "midwhelming"

Comment: @Lambie ... well obviously, I just didn't want to blow my own trumpet that hard.

Comment: I feel like your title and the body of your question don't really correspond, so I'll suggest this here:  does 'responsive' fit the bill? I realize it has more to do with perceived speed, but dictionary.com's "*responding especially readily and **sympathetically***" seems to come close, and I think people start to use it more for an overall smooth experience.

Answer (score 1):

The app is so **straightforward**. The word implies fulfilment of function without elaborate detail.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/straightforward).
> *Straightforward*
> a: free from evasiveness or obscurity : exact, candid
> *a straightforward account*
> b: clear-cut, precise

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/straightforward)
> *straightforward*
> easy to understand or simple

Answer (score -1):

I've always used ['middling' (MW)](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/middling):

> adjective
> **medium, moderate, or average in size, quantity, or quality:** The returns on such a large investment may be only middling.
>
> **mediocre; ordinary; commonplace; pedestrian:** The restaurant's entrées are no better than middling.

I like it because it is means quite obviously in the middle, but also isn't pretentious.